# Rewrite user and password in proxied requests

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I need to rewrite the client authentication scheme in requests going through an Apache 2.4 reverse proxy.
Specifically, I want to ignore the provided username and password, and force the same username + password for all requests.
Is that doable ?

Comment: This is a *very* broken design. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Basically clients will access non-sensitive information on an untrusted server with credentials which need to be kept safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using basic authentication: yes, as that depends on a request header included in every request. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers

> **Note:** If you need to specify custom request headers to be added to the forwarded request, use the [`RequestHeader`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive.

---

> **[`RequestHeader`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader)**
>   This directive can **replace, merge, change or remove HTTP request headers.** The header is modified just before the content handler is run, allowing incoming headers to be modified. ...

And then in your `httpd.conf`:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic <base64-encoded login+password>"
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick !
Added the following line in the VirtualHost definition:

RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic <base64-encoded login+password>"